# Module Based Testing VS Test Library Architecture Testing Framework

Tags: automated-testing, test-automation-framework

I'm fairly new in the world of test automation frameworks and was researching some of the existing methodologies out there. When I came across Module Based Testing and Test Library Architecture Testing I can't understand the exact difference between the two or when i would prefer to use one over the other. If someone could please elaborate. [Source: softwaretestinghelp](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/test-automation-frameworks-selenium-tutorial-20/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between the two is the perspective and focus.  The Module is focused on code specifically and coverage of each module that exists, then they get stacked together for coverage.

The library approach is more designed to organize all the modules in a way to re-use commonalities and decrease the maintenance footprint.

I would also include that this is a specific site preference and not a global industry standard.  Data Driven and Keyword Driven are staples, but the others vary.  Like Page Factory is completely missing from the list, but is a common approach as well.  Frankly I wouldn't consider model and library as separate as they build on each other and are essentially the same thing with minor perspective swaps depending on the context provided.

I would recommend browsing alot of varying sites and get a combined view instead of just using a single site like that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Not to worry, i'm not using a single site. The site i cited just had both methods in it's list. Other sites mostly only take one of the two into their list.